# How to add role assignment on System Assigned Identity using terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform

I have an ansible playbook that execute this command to enable system assigned identity and add "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role on a specific VM.

```
az vm identity assign 
    --name "{{VirtualMachine}}" 
    --resource-group "{{VirtualMachineRG}}" 
    --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" 
    --scope "/subscriptions/{{AzureSID}}/resourceGroups/{{VirtualMachineRG}}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{{VirtualMachine}}
```

Now, the requirement is to move it on terraform template. I already explore terraform official documentation but it lacks examples on how to specify adding role assignment.

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "management_host" {
  name = "management-vm"

  # ...

  identity = {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

output "management_host_identity_object_id" {
  value = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.management_host.identity.0.principal_id
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific examples on how to add a role assignment can be found here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment

In your example the role assignment would probably be along these lines (if you want to assign the role against the scope of a single storage account):

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "blob_contributor" {
  scope                = azurerm_storage_account.your_account.id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.management_host.identity[0].principal_id
}
```